# Android : Find best size for Text based on size of Button

Tags: android, button, text, size

I have a layout and a button in it. In onCreate(), I calculate the size of layout and size of button dynamically. Now based on the size (width) of the button I want to set its TextSize. Initially the button textsize is set to 11, but if the button size increases, the text looks very small. So I need to increase the size of text also.

Is their any method/way where I can calcualte the size of text and check with that of the button size. Any ideas for appropriate method or logic to be applied.

**NOTE :** I want to change the textSize of button based on size of the button and not change buton size based on textSize.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get the paint for the button with `getPaint()` you can use `measureText()` with your text to get the width the text needs for a given `setTextSize()` setting.  You may want to experiment with some spair space.

There is code using to concept for a different case in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478282/dynamically-resize-font-of-textview/8478900#8478900)